# Use two domains with one angular app

Tags: angular, virtualhost, angular-router

We are in the process of migrating our app to a different domain.
In the process, we are going to have a period where some of the app would be on domain A and other parts of the app will be on domain B.

I am trying to have the two different domains handled by one Angular app.

For example

> www.myapp.com --> being handled by module A
>
> www.myotherapp.com --> being handled by module B

Is it possible to achieve something like this within Angular router ?

If not, how would you approach handling this ? (maybe outside of Angular, in the infrastructure level ?)

Comment: It should be possible to target the url to a specific route in your angular application. E.g. www.myapp.com targets www.yourhost.com/ (root of your angular app) and www.myotherapp.com targets www.yourhost.com/#/myroute (if you use hash location strategy). The root module will be loaded in every case, but you should be able to point to different feature modules.

Comment: You can do it as ngfelixl said. If you are using angular-cli you can also host two dedicated apps in a single project  [see here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

I would start by extracting everything that will be needed on the new app to a library. After that, you can build two different apps for each domain, using the extracted stuff as a shared library.

If the extraction / refactoring is done well, the apps will be just thin layers wrapping the library with the actual code.

This is a far cleaner solution to me than trying to pack two different apps into one.

Don't forget that all the unneeded code will be downloaded by the browser if you pack two apps into one.

---- Update ----

Thanks for clarification. You are still talking about two different apps. Your current app (A) and the new shiny one you are going to develop (B). You also want a hybrid solution during the development process (A/B).

On a timeline: A --> A/B --> B.

While you are in the A/B Phase, you want to run the A-Part on a Domain and the B-Part on a different Domain. Usually, one would just use a different Git Branch for the B development without trying to artificially preserve App-A code that is not needed for B. That way, you can deploy each Branch on a different Domain.

Advantages:

- You don't have to manage a temporary hybrid solution
- You can focus on developing B piece by piece on it's own branch
- You have a clean App-A branch for bug-fixes on A
- Separation of concerns is always a good thing :)

Comment: Eventually we am aiming for 1 app. Unneeded content should not be an issue since we are doing lazy loading based on the current route. What you are suggesting sounds like a more complicated solution to me than what I have thought initially.

Comment: What solution did you finally went for? @Michael